SCP a file to multiple Linux locations with prompt
I need to copy a file to multiple (about 500) machines running on proprietary Linux with very limited and special functionality with certain credentials (fixed user and password which are the same on all devices). No open keys or passwordless access are available, I can't install expect there or any other library or package. Ansible is not available as well.
I've created a bash script to copy the file with the IP list file.
But when I launch the script, each device provides the prompt:
"Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])?"
TO continue, I need to type "yes".
How to automate this? How to edit the script to answer "yes" automatically?
Thanks.
I'm a beginner in the scripting. So the script is:
#!/bin/bash
username="username"
while read host; do
  scp $1 $username@${host}:/tmp
done


Try scp -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" … to silence the question. A better approach, however, would be to create a known_hosts file with all the machines in it.

This isn't really a scripting question, since the solution is the same if you were doing it interactively.

BTW, you might want to learn about the yes command. yes | someprogram will answer "y" to any questions it asks.

Please [edit] your question and make clear if the problem is how to avoid or handle the prompt: "Are you sure you want to continue ..." or also how to provide the password.

The whole point of the prompt is because the system doesn't know if there's a man-in-the-middle attack ongoing. If you just automatically type "yes" (or, for that matter, manually type "yes" without actually validating the key), you don't get the security that's the whole point of using SSH.

So if you're a responsible human being who cares about doing their job well, you don't end up in a situation where this prompt needs to be answered at all -- instead, you set up something like LDAP or DNSSEC-based lookup of host keys, or you use SSH certificates to sign the host keys, or so forth. (And you also use keys instead of passwords to authenticate the client -- ideally, keys stored in hardware that software can't copy).

Anyhow, you don't need to install expect on the machines you're logging into, just the machine you're logging into them from; so all the existing answers using expect still apply. And the options to turn off host key checking altogether by adding extra command line arguments to your ssh client likewise still apply, as awful a practice as that is.

(Jumping back to my earlier notes about storing host keys in LDAP or DNS -- that doesn't require any reconfiguration on the devices being logged into, so it doesn't matter that they're simple, proprietary embedded systems; it's only the client that needs to know how to retrieve public keys for the server it's logging into; the server doesn't need to do anything special to support that)

Thank you all for your lessons on how to be responsible, use SSH certificates, or what to modify on 500 devices where any modification is not allowed. These 500 devices have unix-based proprietary OS, Linux-like command syntaxis and it's not allowed to modify any file (or settings) without special recommendations from the vendor. Seems to be I made a mistake asking the question here. The "community" prefer to teach how to live rather than to answer the question. I've found a way to use expect on the source host.

Using expect on the source host is one of the suggested solutions found in these comments and linked answers. You are of course free to ignore the other suggestions - but personally I think its helpful to get other ideas even if they aren't so easy or practical in your real world situation.
